# convert double quotes to single quotes in string?

Tags: r, string, dplyr

In R, if you have the following string, which is a vector and each element is in double quotes:

```
values <- c("hello","mr")
```

How can one go about creating the following string instead?

```
"'hello','mr'"
```

As in how do i add in those single quotes, but ensure the entire string is one sentence wrapped in double quotes?

I can hard code this with `paste0` but it's not the same thing.

Comment: For what purpose do you want the single quotes? Depending on the purpose, different functions might be more appropriate.

Comment: It will be passed into a SQL IN operator - however, glue_sql cannot be used as it is not an DBI connection

Comment: OK, in that case **do not use the solutions below!** Doing so will expose you to fatal security holes. You **must** use a proper SQL interface solution. If you’re not using DBI, then figure out how your SQL interface supports prepared statements and use those. I repeat, *never*, **never** manually quote SQL input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple `stringr` solution:

```
library(stringr)
str_c("'",values,"'", collapse = ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sQuote` and `paste`:

```r
paste(sQuote(values, q = FALSE), collapse = ",")
# [1] "'hello','mr'"
```

Comment: `shQuote` will produce wrong results (and is the wrong function, check the documentation!). You want `sQuote(x, q = FALSE)`.

Comment: Oh, you're right! do you wanna make it a proper answer?

Comment: Actually, my bad, it should be either `q = FALSE`, or `q = c("'", "'", '"', '"'))`. The latter is more flexible but too convoluted for OP’s use-case.

Comment: Is there not a version using stringr instead?

Comment: @KonradRudolph you seem more knowledgable than me, no worries if you wanna give a more lengthy answer.